# necessary and sufficient condition for convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{a^n\prod\limits_{j=0}^{n}f(j)}$

Tags: calculus

Assume $a>0$, and for all $n$ we have $0 \leq f(n) \leq 1$.

Is there a **necessary and sufficient** condition on the series $f(n)$ for which

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{a^n\prod\limits_{j=0}^{n}f(j)}<\infty$  ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the ratio test should leave you with very particular case.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem doesn't state $1>a>0$?

Comment: $0<a<\infty$, nothing more..